# How fast is 1 MHz?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, clock

How fast is 1 MHz in an AVR microcontroller? Is it actually 1,000,000 Hz or is it 1,048,576 Hz (1,024 Hz * 1,024)?

Comment: outside of computer memory applications the si units are actual SI units. So Hz will be correct.

Comment: You would be better served to use an external crystal. The internal oscillator is awful.

Comment: @MattYoung Thanks for the tip. I wondered one time why my AVR timer circuit was off by a couple seconds per minute. ;)

Comment: The datasheet for an ATtiny13 (chapter 18.4 "Clock Characteristics") mentions Factory calibration for 4.8 and 9.6 MHz @ 10% accuracy.  User calibration can improve that to 2%.

Comment: Nobody's insane enough to invent binary versions of hertz and still call them hertz, thank god.

Comment: @jippie Don't want to sound too dumb... but what is "user calibration"? Or is that worthy of its own question?

Comment: Most, if not all, AVR has the ability to slightly change the internal RC oscillator frequency by programming a register. You can use that register to get closer to the desired frequency, hence user calibration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hz are always SI units Mega = 10^6 or one million.

Strictly speaking 2^20 should use the Mi (Mebi) prefix for all applications. I know that those prefixes were codified rather late, but it was still in the 1990's and have been in popular usage for over a decade.

Answer (score 2):

kilo = 1024 only for memory size terms, for others its kilo = 1000. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Yes but only for coding purposes does kilo=1024.  If you buy memory sticks or drives they use the SI value as a short hand.  Read the small print for actual memory size.